# Multi-Precision calculations using Boost in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, visual-studio-2019, precision

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 with Qt to develop an application. In the code, at certain places, the temporary values go above or below the value that can be handled using a `double`. Since `long double` is the same as `double` in Visual C++, I decided to use Boost Multiprecision library. To test it I included `#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"`, when building my project I get a lot of errors (2233 to be exact), a subset of these errors are:

```
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2059: syntax error: 'static_cast' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-parameter-list, found '>' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2059: syntax error: ')' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(811,7): error C2974: 'boost::Mutable_ForwardContainer': invalid template argument for 'C', type expected (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(705): message : see declaration of 'boost::Mutable_ForwardContainer' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(815,5): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(815,5): error C2059: syntax error: ',' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(815,7): error C2974: 'boost::DefaultConstructible': invalid template argument for 'TT', type expected (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(136): message : see declaration of 'boost::DefaultConstructible' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2059: syntax error: 'static_cast' (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-parameter-list, found '>' (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2059: syntax error: ')' (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(816,3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(816,3): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) (compiling source file plotwidget.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(810,3): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(811,7): error C2974: 'boost::Mutable_ForwardContainer': invalid template argument for 'C', type expected (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(705): message : see declaration of 'boost::Mutable_ForwardContainer' (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(815,5): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(815,5): error C2059: syntax error: ',' (compiling source file plotpaint.cpp)
```

After doing a lot of research, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42041243/6095822) answer which states:

> The problem is caused by the fact that some templates in `boost::multiprecision` use `std::unary_function`, which has been deprecated since C++11 and was removed from the standard for C++17.

The `README` file in Boost Multiprecision Library states:

> ANNOUNCEMENT: Support for C++03 is now removed from this library.  Any attempt to build with a non C++11 conforming compiler is doomed to failure.

I am using C++17 and my project is dependent on it, so I guess, I cannot use `boost::multiprecision` at all? or is there a way I can force it?

I'm just looking for a type that has higher precision than a `double` (*preferably 128-bit*) and be able to perform elementary functions (+, -, *, /) on it. Is there any way I can achieve that?

EDIT:
Since `boost::multipricision` is a header-only library, I am not building boost at all.

EDIT 2: Just to be clear, my entire process is as follows:
-- Download boost
-- Unzip it using 7-Zip and place the boost_1_76_0 in C:\Program Files\boost
-- Add the C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_76_0 in Additional Include Directories
-- Do `#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"` in only one of my header file.

This is all I am doing that is generating the error. If I comment out the `#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"` from my header file then everything works just fine.

Comment: @Chaitanya They provide a workaround in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42041243/260313

Comment: @rturrado that's the same answer that I have linked. I tried that workaround but it is not useful as the feature that is being enabled by `#define _HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC 1` is removed from C++17 onwards.

Comment: @S.M. Thanks! But then why does the library states `Any attempt to build with a non C++11 conforming compiler is doomed to failure.`? Are you sure I can use `boost::multipricision` with C++17?

Comment: If you show the code, **as plain text**, that's generating the error, we could more easily help you.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews there is no code. All I am doing is downloading boost, unzipping it, placing it in `C:Program Files\boost` and then adding boost root folder in `Additional Include Directories` and then `#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"` in one of my header files.

Comment: @S.M. Thanks a lot! I didn't even know we could test it like that :)

Comment: @S.M. I was just following the guide on boost's website: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/more/getting_started/windows.html which says `The most reliable way to get a copy of Boost is to download boost_1_76_0.7z or boost_1_76_0.zip and unpack it to install a complete Boost distribution.` and then later at the footer `We recommend downloading boost_1_76_0.7z and using 7-Zip to decompress it.`

Comment: @S.M. I can install the latest boost version from the link you gave me. However, I am wondering is there any way I can just get the boost::multiprecision only? I don't need anything else from boost library and I would like to avoid the complete installation if possible. I tried to look for it but I am unable to find any resources that could guide me through the process, if you know of any resource that can be useful then I will be very grateful :)

Comment: @S.M. Installing `boost_1_76_0-msvc-14.2-64` did not solve the problem. Although, not I am able to include `#include "boost/array.hpp"` but for if I do `#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"` it gives me same error again

Comment: You may reinstall windows. You don't want to post all true error messages. I am done here.